# Nested loop in r giving conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements, rstudio, nested-loops

```
    CLID <-c(1,2,1,2)
SUBJ<- c(1,2,3,4)

df<-cbind.data.frame(CLID,SUBJ)

for (TRT in df$CLID){
  for (SUB in df$SUBJ){
if (CLID == 1 & SUBJ==1) {
  df$TRT <- paste("A") 
 } else if  (CLID==1 & SUBJ==2) {
   df$TRT <- paste("B")
  }else if (CLID==1 & SUBJ==4) {
  (TRT <- "C")
  df$TRT <- paste("C")
  }else {
  df$TRT <- paste("NA")
    }
    }
  }
```

I am try to created a new column with unique combinations of Subject and CLID. The expected the code is creating a new columns but the output is not as expected. It should be a combination of both but that is not what is happening. How can i make sure that new column which is created is a combination of both the conditions ?

The expected outcome is this:

```
CLID <-c(1,2,1,2)
SUBJ<- c(1,2,3,4)
TRT<-c("A","NA","NA","C")

df_expected<-cbind.data.frame(CLID,SUBJ,TRT)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. It doesn't match your expected output though. Nowhere in your loop do you have that if CLID == 2 and SUBJ == 4 that TRT should be C.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(TRT = case_when(
    CLID == 1 & SUBJ == 1 ~ "A",
    CLID == 1 & SUBJ == 2 ~ "B",
    CLID == 1 & SUBJ == 4 ~ "C"
  ))
#>   CLID SUBJ  TRT
#> 1    1    1    A
#> 2    2    2 <NA>
#> 3    1    3 <NA>
#> 4    2    4 <NA>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the loop to do the same

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$CLID[i] == 1 & df$SUBJ[i] == 1){
    df$TRT[i] <- "A"
  }
  else if(df$CLID[i] == 1 & df$SUBJ[i] == 2){
    df$TRT[i] <- "B"
  }
  else if(df$CLID[i] == 1 & df$SUBJ[i] == 4){
    df$TRT[i] <- "C"
  }
  else{
    df$TRT[i] <- NA
  }
}

df
#>   CLID SUBJ  TRT
#> 1    1    1    A
#> 2    2    2 <NA>
#> 3    1    3 <NA>
#> 4    2    4 <NA>
```

or another option using nested `ifelse` statements.

```
df$TRT <- ifelse(df$CLID == 1 & df$SUBJ == 1, "A", 
                 ifelse(df$CLID == 1 & df$SUBJ == 2, "B",
                        ifelse(df$CLID == 1 & df$SUBJ == 4, "C", NA)))

df
#>   CLID SUBJ  TRT
#> 1    1    1    A
#> 2    2    2 <NA>
#> 3    1    3 <NA>
#> 4    2    4 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try and get back. I knew there was a way with dplyr using mutate but did not know what function.

Comment: It is working as expected. I was wondering if you can show the same using a loop? Thanks